# Empty object x-ray scraper in node.js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, x-ray

I want to get the first link of the result of here http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q=tired+adele

using [x-ray node.js scraper](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray). And my code as below :

```
x('http://search.azlyrics.com/search.php?q=tired+adele', {
    link: x('body > div.container.main-page > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > a')
})(function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Not sure why I got empty object. The selector seems doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked the err object?

Comment: In x-ray an empty object means a filled err

Answer (score 0):

there is no tbody in the source html. remove it from your code and it will work